# does av_read_frame add FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I'm using libav to read an MPEG stream.
I'm using the function `av_read_frame()` to read some frames into packets:

```
av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)
```

I then use the function `avcodec_decode_video2` to decode the packet into frame.
the documentation of the function `avcodec_decode_video2` contains the following warning:

> The input buffer must be FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE larger than the
>   actual read bytes because some optimized bitstream readers read 32 or
>   64 bits at once and could read over the end. The end of the input
>   buffer buf should be set to 0 to ensure that no overreading happens
>   for damaged MPEG streams.

I wanted to know if the function `av_read_frame` doesn't already allocate the additional FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, av_read_frame() always adds FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE for you. You only need to care about that if you use your own demuxed data as input to avcodec_decode_video2(), e.g. if you write your own demuxers (like what VLC or mplayer do).